# $.ajax post to PHP file throwing 405 method not allowed

Tags: php, ajax, nginx, digital-ocean, http-status-code-405

I'm using a PHP contact form for a site hosted on Nginx with Digital Ocean. I'm totally new to PHP. I installed sendmail using this article -https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/php-mail-function-enable.
On submit the form errors 405 Method not allowed.  The .js and the .php files are both in the root directory so I don't think it's a CORS issue.

contact_me.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST;
if(empty($_POST['name'])                ||
   empty($_POST['email'])               ||
   empty($_POST['message'])     ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
        echo "No arguments Provided!";
        return false;
   }
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$to = 'mygmailaccount@gmail.com';
$email_subject = "Portfolio Contact:  $name";
$email_body = "Name: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@example.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;                    
?>
```

contact_me.js

```
    $(function() {

    $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            console.log('contact_me.js submitSuccess running'); // this prints
            event.preventDefault();
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var firstName = name;
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.example.com/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    email: email,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                console.log('ajax success function'); // doesn't print
                },
                error: function() {
                console.log('ajax error function'); // this prints
                }
            })
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        }
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});
```

I was posting to a Firebase backend before attempting the PHP, and the ajax works there.  Any advice would be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: You have to show some code if you want some reaction

Comment: Seems like it's not a problem with your code. Seems like a problem with your webserver's settings. Do any POST requests work? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications

Comment: @BrandonFlynn-NB - yes, other POSTs work. I've been looking at this tutorial https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/mail-proxy/ but I'm stuck on the auth_http (step 3).  Should this be the path to the php file?

Comment: The issue is definitely with the web server configuration - not with the shown PHP code. By the way, using a `return` statement outside of a function has no point.